# VCalendar Description coming in as Blank

Tags: vb.net

I have created an ICS file in VB.NET and everything works properly except that when some users receive the calendar file attachment in their email The description is coming in as Blank.

I am using the code below. Can someone please advise what I am missing?

```
        Dim icsTextWriter As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("Files/" & strFileName))
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("VERSION:2.0")
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN")
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("BEGIN:VEVENT")
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("DTSTART:" + strDTStart)
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("DTEND:" + strDTEnd)
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("LOCATION:" + strLocation)
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("SUMMARY:" + Summary)
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION: Test Description")
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("END:VEVENT")
        icsTextWriter.WriteLine("END:VCALENDAR")
        icsTextWriter.Close()
```

Comment: Is there anything different about the mail client(s) being used where the description appears to be blank?

Comment: I cannot find anything Different. we are on the same network. and our outlook versions are the same. I get the description but the network technician guy is not getting the description.

Comment: It's hard to see how we can help if you can't tell us the difference between the cases where it works and the cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: And what is this secret Outlook version number? It could be important - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Events_.28VEVENT.29) states "Outlook 2002 and Outlook 2003 demand a UID and a DTSTAMP".

Comment: Blackwood. I don't know the difference. I have compared my outlook settings with the other IT guys settings and they are the same. We are on Outlook 2010 on premise. Outlook Version 14.0.7165.5000 32 bit

Comment: I added the following line:                                                     icsTextWriter.WriteLine("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:" + Description) and my issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: @Isaiah You seem to have discovered useful information, so if you make your comment about needing an "X-ALT-DESC" field into an answer (and later accept it) then other people will be able to find it.